# Suggestions for dealing with IE's terrible Javascript / Dom accessing engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I'm working on a site that has a page that can potentially become very long.  It can have in theory 1000+ rows of data in it.  Then these rows could each have sub-rows.

I'm currently using a list / sublist structure to represent the data because it's difficult to visualize subsets in tables.  the subset data is in a table though.

The Problem is this:  In IE.   my hovering over the row styles,  tooltips and other javascripts are taking upwards of 5 seconds to fire!   The page hangs like crazy and is pretty much unuseable.  In FF, Chrome, and Safari it works just fine.

I don't need a whole bunch of stats saying IE is slow. i know it is. what i need is some suggestions / theories/ ideas on how to combat the slowness!

Some of the ideas i've had so far:
-some kind of paging mechanism.   But that gets tricky b/c 1.  It's a list not a table, and 2.  it's got sub sub lists and sub tables for those sub lists.   so we'd need to somehow page based on the top level i think.  because we don't want to split the data up at all.    I guess that might be feasible...

-some kind of mechanism that holds the content in a javascript array or object or soomething and doesn't add it to the dom until it's been scrolled to.   and takes it away when you scroll past it.  in theory this would be cool. but i think it would be horrible to impliment.

-something else entirely?

Thanks in Advance for any ideas!  I'm probably going to try and put a bounty on this as soon as i'm able to help inspire you ;)

EDIT:

OH MY!  I think i may have found part of the problem using dyna trace!  thanks Pointy for reminding me about this tool. i had forgotten about out.   the click event of one of my buttons seems to be firing an insane amount.  like 2000 times and count.  something is clicking it automatically or something crazy like that.   weird thing is, i don't have any javascripts that trigger that button click!  EDIT:  This doesn't seem to be an issue anymore.

EDIT:

Also: i don't think it is the complexity of my markup that is affecting the responsiveness of my scripts(i know if i could use just id selectors it would be best, but i've optimized my selectors and qtips as much as possible (with help from s.o. in the past).  i have a button that is just on the page, not nested in anything,  that the click handler takes 4 or 5 seconds to register.  It's not that the click action takes a long time, it's just slow to notice that it's been clicked.

EDIT: i had 5 spans that were each nested in a span unnecessarily,  i un-nested those and it seems to have cut the slowness in about 1/2!!    (these 5 spans were repeated in every row)

EDIT:   Here's some of the relevant scripts:

The Main Button Handler:

```
$('#FilterScheduledShifts').click(function () {
  var categoryId = $('#CategoryId').val();
  var activityId = $('#ActivityId').val();
  var shiftStatusFilters = GetShiftStatusFilterIds();
  var dayOfWeekFilters = GetDayOfWeekFilters();
  var startDateFilter = GetStartDateFilter();
  var endDateFilter = GetStartEndFilter();
  var dataToPost = {
    categoryId: categoryId,
    activityId: activityId,
    statuses: shiftStatusFilters,
    daysOfWeek: dayOfWeekFilters,
    startDate: startDateFilter,
    endDate: endDateFilter
  };
  var url = $('#UrlToFilter').val();
  $('#ListHolder').html("<%=web.loading %>");
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: dataToPost,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
      document.getElementById('ScheduledActivityShiftListHolder').innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function () {
      v2ErrorNotice(v2Text.shared.genericAjaxErrorMessage);
    }
  });
});
```

The Get...FIlter functions are very simple functions that run in a few milliseconds... nothing interesting or noteworthy happening in there.

this bit attaches some of the behaviour that is very slow:
in other pages they react nice and quick, on this page... 2-3 seconds.

```
$('span.infoCard').die();
$('span.infoCard').live("mouseover", function () {

  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.data("toolTipAttached")) {

    var title = '';

    if ($this.attr('infoCardTitle') != "") {
      title = $this.attr('infoCardTitle');
    } else {
      title = $this.html();
    }

    $this.qtip({
      content: {
        text: "loading",
        title: title,
        ajax: {
          url: $this.attr('urlToGet')
          // data: data,
        }
      },
      position: {
        at: 'right middle',
        my: 'left top',
        adjust: {
          screen: 'flip'
        }
      },
      hide: {
        fixed: true,
        when: 'mouseout'
      },
      show: {
        solo: true,
        delay: 500,
        ready: true
      },
      style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light InfoCardTip',
        widget: true,
        tip: {
          corner: true,
          width: 15,
          height: 15
        }
      }
    });
    $this.data("toolTipAttached", true);
  }
});
```

There are 2 different versions of this for 2 different classes, one gets a single "shift" one gets the user s for a bunch of shifts. as with other things.  once the function itself runs quick,  the ajax is fast, the v2ReLoadScheduledActivitySection runs in about 50 ms. nothing interesting in there. :

```
$('div.GetShiftUserArrow').die('click');
$('div.GetShiftUserArrow').live('click', function () {
  var listIsVisible = $(this).attr('listIsVisible');
  var holder = $('#' + $(this).attr('listHolder'));
  var activityHolder = $('#TopLevel{0}'.format($(this).attr('activityShiftId')));

  if (listIsVisible == -1) {
    v2ReLoadScheduledActivitySection($(this), 1);
  } else {
    holder.empty().toggle('hide');
    $(this).removeClass('GetShiftUserArrowOpen');
    $(this).attr('listIsVisible', listIsVisible * -1);
  }
});
```

Here's a bit of the HTML. this is the

for a day... the main list has one of these for every day of the year (or whatever range they pick).  There could be any number of sub li's in that list, but it tends to be between 1-10.

```
<li class="EntityRow" style="font-weight:normal;">
 <div class="TopLevelRow" sectiondate="1/21/2011 12:00:00 AM">
  <div class="ScheduleDayHeader OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0px;font-weight:normal;">
   <div class="Buttons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="GetDayUserArrow OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" listisvisible="-1" sectiondate="1/21/2011 12:00:00 AM" url="/This/IsNot/TheReal/Url"></div>
   </div><span class="CategorizedNameHolder OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="display:inline-block; width:380px;padding-bottom:2px;">Friday, January 21, 2011</span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">Start</span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">End</span> <span class="StatusIcons">Status</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn GlossaryMe" tooltip="A Number">Mn</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn GlossaryMe" tooltip="A Number">Mx</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn GlossaryMe" tooltip="A Number">BU</span> <span class=
   "SkinnyColumn GlossaryMe" tooltip="A Number">Av</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn GlossaryMe" tooltip="Assigned">As</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn GlossaryMe" tooltip="A Number">Co</span>
  </div>

  <div class="ShiftListHolder" sectiondate="1/21/2011 12:00:00 AM">
   <ul class="ScheduledActivitiesForDayList EntityList FancyList SubList">
    <li class="EntityRow" activityshiftid="4645" id="ListItemFor4645">
     <div class="BlueOnHover ScheduleShiftHeader" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="Buttons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
       <div class="GetShiftUserArrow OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" listisvisible="-1" activityshiftid="4645" url="/Some/Url=4645" sectiondate="1/21/2011 12:00:00 AM"></div>
      </div><span class="CategorizedNameHolder OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="display:inline-block; width:350px;padding-bottom:2px;"><span class="AssignLink" activityshiftid="4645">SomeText</span></span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">9:00 AM</span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">12:30 PM</span>

      <div class="StatusIcons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7">
       <div class='TipMe LegendMe ClassToPickTheIcon' tooltip='Min # scheduled' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>3</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe OtherClassToPickTheIcon' tooltip='Unlocked' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>2</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe AnotherClassToPickTheIcon' tooltip='Do not auto assign' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>1</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe ClassToPickTheIconAgain' tooltip='Do not autolock' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>1</span>
       </div>
      </div><span class="OnlyFloatLeftInIE7"><span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">1</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">--</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">0</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">0</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="Assigned">2</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip=
      "A Number">0</span></span>
     </div>

     <div class="UserListHoder" id="UserListHolder4645" activityshiftid="4645"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="EntityRow" activityshiftid="4129" id="ListItemFor4129">
     <div class="BlueOnHover ScheduleShiftHeader" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="Buttons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
       <div class="GetShiftUserArrow OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" listisvisible="-1" activityshiftid="4129" url="/Some/Url=4129" sectiondate="1/21/2011 12:00:00 AM"></div>
      </div><span class="CategorizedNameHolder OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="display:inline-block; width:350px;padding-bottom:2px;"><span class="AssignLink" activityshiftid="4129">Blah Bla blah</span></span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">9:00 AM</span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">5:00 PM</span>

      <div class="StatusIcons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7">
       <div class='TipMe LegendMe ClassToPickTheIcon' tooltip='Min # scheduled' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>3</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe OtherClassToPickTheIcon' tooltip='Unlocked' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>2</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe AnotherClassToPickTheIcon' tooltip='Do not auto assign' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>1</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe OtherClassForIcon' tooltip='on availabilities' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>2</span>
       </div>
      </div><span class="OnlyFloatLeftInIE7"><span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">1</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">5</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">0</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">0</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="Assigned">5</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip=
      "A Number">0</span></span>
     </div>

     <div class="UserListHoder" id="UserListHolder4129" activityshiftid="4129"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="EntityRow" activityshiftid="3534" id="ListItemFor3534">
     <div class="BlueOnHover ScheduleShiftHeader" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="Buttons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
       <div class="GetShiftUserArrow OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" listisvisible="-1" activityshiftid="3534" url="/Some/Url=3534" sectiondate="1/21/2011 12:00:00 AM"></div>
      </div><span class="CategorizedNameHolder OnlyFloatLeftInIE7" style="display:inline-block; width:350px;padding-bottom:2px;"><span class="AssignLink" activityshiftid="3534">even more</span></span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">1:00 PM</span> <span class="TimeHolderSpan">4:30 PM</span>

      <div class="StatusIcons OnlyFloatLeftInIE7">
       <div class='TipMe LegendMe SchedulingFullyA NumberIcon' tooltip='Min # A Number' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>4</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe LockedIcon' tooltip='Locked' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>1</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe ClassToPickTheIconAgain' tooltip='Auto assign' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>2</span>
       </div>

       <div class='TipMe LegendMe OtherClassForIcon' tooltip='on assignments' legendgroupid='5'>
        <span class='NoDisplay'>3</span>
       </div>
      </div><span class="OnlyFloatLeftInIE7"><span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">1</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">5</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">0</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="A Number">0</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip="Assigned">7</span> <span class="SkinnyColumn TipMe ContentToolTip" tooltip=
      "A Number">3</span></span>
     </div>

     <div class="UserListHoder" id="UserListHolder3534" activityshiftid="3534"></div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
 ​
```

anything with TipMe, or GlossaryMe brings up a qtip tooltip.

like this:

```
 $(".TipMe").live("mouseover", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.removeAttr('title');
  $this.removeAttr('alt');

  if (!$this.data("toolTipAttached")) {

    $this.qtip({
      show: {
        ready: true,
        solo: true,
        delay: 500
      },
      style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light InfoCardTip',
        widget: true
      },
      content: $this.attr('tooltip'),
      position: {
        at: 'bottomRight',
        my: 'topleft',
        adjust: {
          screen: 'flip',
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        }
      },
      hide: {
        fixed: true,
        inactive: 1000
      }
    });
    $this.data("toolTipAttached", true);
    //    $this.trigger("mouseover");
  }
});
```

Something tells me it might be all my tooltip handlers that are causing the problem...

Let me know if you guys want anything else!

Comment: I suggest you try to get dynaTrace Ajax working, and do some profiling to find out what's taking the most time.

Comment: I could say **example** or gtfo, but I probably won't. :)

Comment: @galambalazs :  it's a list,  with each <li>  having as sub <ul>, and each <li> in the sub <ul> could have a table.   they also each have 10 or so spans/divs. and an image or 2.  the tables are very simple, only 5 columns.

Comment: @Patrica - If the answer is important to you **take your time and provide a test page**! Don't expect us to recreate your problems. Thanks.

Comment: alright alright, i'll try to get an an example somewhere... Posting the page, and all the scripts with it simply isn't an option,  but i can put in the scripts that are relevant to the problem (i think).  and a chunk of the html... I just need to comb through it for any "sensative" info and such.

Comment: heh, i maxed out the allowed post length!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "I don't think it is the **complexity of** my **markup** that is affecting the responsiveness of my scripts"

False assumptions are the worst leaders of the mind. It's interesting because you also said:

> "this bit attaches some of the behaviour that is very slow, **in other pages** they react **nice and quick**, on this page... 2-3 seconds."
>
> "i had 5 spans that were each **nested** in a span **unnecessarily**, i un-nested those and it seems to have **cut the slowness** in about 1/2!! (these 5 spans were repeated in every row)"

There you go. :)

What you can try is to change *[`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)* handlers to *[`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)*. The main difference between them is that *`live`* attaches *The Handler* to the document, while in case of *`delegate`* you can specify where to attach it. I think this can be the tipping point. Also try *[`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)* which fires *less* frequently.

```
$('#ROOT').delegate(".infoCard", "mouseenter", function () { ... })
```

`root` can be any element depending on your site. You can try the parent `<ul>` for example.

Another thing to try is to use your own handler (but you can't use *`mouseenter`* then):

```
$("#ROOT").mouseover(function (e) {
    var $this = $(e.target);
    if ($this.hasClass('TipMe')) {
        // TipMe code...
    } else if ($this.hasClass('infoCard')) {
        // infoCard code...
    }
});
```

Let me know if any of them helped! :)

Comment: galambalazs: I completely agree with your advice to use `delegate()` instead of `.live()`. Just one thing. With regard to your comment *"Also try mouseenter which fires less frequently"*, that won't actually make a difference. Since `mouseenter` doesn't bubble at all (and doesn't exist outside IE), it is useless for event delegation and jQuery doesn't actually use it for its `delegate/live` handlers. They just map it to `mouseover` then report it as `mouseenter`. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/KuULg/) They only started reporting it that way in `1.4.3`. *(Not a good idea IMO.)*

Comment: I know `mouseenter` is IE-only and it's mouseover when delegated, but still it **fires less frequently**: http://jsbin.com/ikeqa4/10/edit (event handlers are executed *fewer times*, because there's another `<span>` in every TipMe)

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Very good point. +1 When you said that mouseenter fires less frequently, I was more focused on the firing of the selector against the elements in the path. You're absolutely right that the handler itself function will fire more frequently with `mouseover`.

Comment: I'll try this out first thing monday!

Comment: i can't seem to get using delegate working for the infoCard class.  i tried a bunch of different options as the root.  it's not throwing an error or anything, but i put an alert in there and it's not firing.  
i tried : $('ul').delegate('.infoCard', 'mouseover', function () {
and : $('#ScheduledActivityList').delegate('.infoCard', 'mouseover', function () {
and $('body').delegate('.infoCard', 'mouseover', function () {

Comment: @Patricia - What version are you using? It needs v1.4.2+ http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: heh, that might be the problem, i think i have 1.4.1 i'll update and report back

Comment: that would have been to easy,  still not doing anything, but no errors either. (ie IE and FF)

Comment: Well it's hard to tell without seeing the site. You can check it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ikeqa4/11/ with the logic you've given.

Comment: good news!  i was able to get the 2nd option working!   the page is much snappier now.   the hovers still take a bit, but it's in the acceptable range!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer galambalazs - a well deserved bounty on this one :)

Answer (score 5):

Hard to give a concrete answer without knowing what your code looks like.

If you're just doing a little style change on hover, then I'd suggest you use CSS instead of javascript to accomplish it.

The `:hover` pseudo selector won't work on a `<tr>` in IE6, but it will work in the other browsers.

```
#myTable tr:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

For those items that require javascript, we would really need to see the code to know why it is slow. It sounds like you may be doing unnecessary DOM selection.

Even if performance can be improved via pagination or something similar to reduce the size, it could be that you still have some inefficient code that should be tightened up a bit.

Comment: +1 - although IE may not be fast, due to different implementations, inefficient code will also affect browsers differently

Comment: i switched the hover behaviour over to this and that is working nicely now, thanks for that.  i really don't know why i didn't think of use the pseudo selectors before!!

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help for my button clicks and tooltips and other stuff taking forever.

Comment: @Patricia: With regard to using `.live()` for your button clicks, how many `.live()` handlers are you assigning? It isn't typical to use `.live()` to assign a hander to work with an element based on its ID. Are there many redundant handlers being assigned?

Comment: not sure what you mean by redundant,  i only have that call once.  i have a few other things being wired up with live, but they are all class based.

Comment: oh, also, i chnaged that to be a normal click handler with the same results.

Comment: @Patricia: I just meant if you have several buttons that do the same thing that are being assigned individual `.live()` handlers. Sounds like that's not the case. In your handlers, make sure that you are doing as little DOM selection as possible. DOM selection is going to be very slow in IE, especially if you have many elements on the page. If there's any way to cache an element that is being selected more than once, then do that. Even if it is a set of elements. It is better to cache a set, and do a `.filter()` on them to get the one(s) you need rather than going back to the DOM to reselect.

Comment: @Patricia: So does it still seem that the cause of the issue is this mysterious recursive triggering of the click event? Or did you work that part out?

Comment: that seems to have stopped happening!  but it's still taking a good 2-3 seconds to respond to any javascripty interaction on the page.  which is about 1/2 what it was before i slimmed down the dom a bit.

Comment: @Patricia: Eliminate `.live()` entirely from your code. Where it makes sense to do event delegation, use `.delegate()` instead. Another example of where to *not* use `.live()` is your `$('#buttonId').live()`. It would be better to assign the handler directly, especially if it is deeply nested. If you have many handlers attached to some repetitive element in the table using `.click()` or `.bind('click')`, that should be replaced with `.delegate()`, like: `$('#myList').delegate('.myPerRowLink','click',function(){...});` So if you have 1,000 rows, you'll now have 1 handler instead of 1,000.

Comment: ...ultimately, this is all guesswork. Providing your code with a description or sample of the HTML it is working on would be the greatest help.

Comment: @Patricia: Regarding your update, as I said get rid of *all* uses of `.live()`. Never ever use it. You can *always* use `.delegate()` in its stead.

Comment: ...overall, jQuery's event delegation system is convenient, but doing your own will likely be more efficient.

Comment: i can't seem to get delegate to work on my page!  i tried putting it instead of the TipMes and the infoCards... neither worked.  Strangely though, in a jsFiddle with some of the html copied it did work... what would interfere with that?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using jQuery selectors to perform whatever action it is you're doing. I would definitely look into a paging mechanism though. At a certain point the amount of HTML you're throwing at the rendering engine becomes a problem.

Comment: it's not actually the rendering that's the problem,  it renders at an acceptable speed, it's the javascript functionality after it renders that's the problem.

Comment: Still, the amount of HTML you're loading has to be parsed by JavaScript.  The more HTML there is, the more the JavaScript engine has to do.  IE's JavaScript engine isn't nearly as powerful as Chrome's, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

check out the endless scroll jquery plugin. This will not solve performance issues in IE per se, but will allow you to try some paging techniques without page breaks to see if that will work as a solution.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/endless-scroll

Comment: neat plugin! similar to what i had in mind, but i don't think it's quite right b/c it seems to leave what is scrolled out of view by scrolling up in the dom.

Comment: I would personally modify this plugin to suite your needs, if its pretty much what you want but has some small issue I think tackling them small issues would be the fasted method of resolving your issue

Answer (score 0):

Some real markup would help, I'm assuming you have something like (at least as a silhouette of the structure.)

```
<div class="list">
  <div id="item1">list html here</div>
  <div id="item2">list html here</div>
  <div id="item3">list html here</div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div id="item999990">list html here</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the scan of a list of that many items is pretty slow.

Is there a way to break the list down heirarchically in the markup, even if that is not displayed graphically.

so

```
<div class="list">
  <div id="cat1">
    <div id="item1">list html here</div>
    <div id="item2">list html here</div>
    <div id="item3">list html here</div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="item120">list html here</div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div id="cat97">
    <div id="item99904">list html here</div>
    <div id="item99905">list html here</div>
    <div id="item99906">list html here</div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="item999990">list html here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this way the scans under the items under each level are of much smaller sets.  I haven't seen your exact problem, and this may not be possible, but if you could accomplish something like this your seek times for selectors should improve dramatically.

Comment: Does grouping actually work as expected with id's, I can understand the theory with classes, and pseudo selectors, but I would of thought Id's are indexed some way there for there not traversed when the DOM is looking up the element

Comment: I really don't know the exact dom algorithms used, but I would think one of the great things about markup is that you can immediately eliminate large portions of it while you are searching based on the hierarchy.  if your selector is just #item443 then I would expect it to scan the whole dom document, however, if it was div #cat42 #item443 or div > #cat42 > #item443 then I would expect it to only look for #item443 in the nodes that are children of #cat42, not even looking at the rest of the document, and thus hopefully saving a fair amount of time.

Comment: interesting theory Matthew... i wonder if there are any studies to back this up.   i know id selectors are the fastest b/c they use document.getElementById... but would nesting them make them faster... hmmm.   either way.  One of the things on my page that is slow is near the very top level of the dom, not nested deep at all, and it has the same slow reaction as the heavily nested things.

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript uses a lot of memory when run in IE, that could slow things down.  Check memory consumption by looking at the iexplore.exe process in Windows Task Manager.  If it turns out IE is using a lot of memory, try to optimize your code.  Particularly look for:

- Closures that may not be going out of scope - especially nested closures
- Circular references between the dom and your script
- Excessive unnecessary persistent dom references within your script

Another thing you might try is to use `document.querySelector` to find elements without ids in IE8/IE9/chrome/firefox (or `element.querySelector`).  IE7 users will have to suffer, but that's what you get for not upgrading!  ;-)